# KernelPnP 219 : Driver intelHaxm.sys crash

Tags: windows-10, drivers, crash

My Enterprise computer is oftently crashes, today in the event viewer  i found  in system logs , this warning :

**KernelPnp 219**, so  i doubt that this could be the source of error.

I googled it, and i found an answer  [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9684c68-fa72-4597-84dc-333b68791d43/kernel-pnp-219-error-crashes-pc-no-clue-why?forum=win10itprogeneral) , suggesting to run *Driver verifer* .

so i run it [following this steps](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/driver-verifier-tracking-down-a-mis-behaving/f5cb4faf-556b-4b6d-95b3-c48669e4c983) and i found that **intelHaxm.sys** is the driver causing the crash.

What should i fix?  that driver ?

## Update

I searched ,as it's suggested in comments,if i have **intelhaxm.sys** installed , i found  under `C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM` it 's version is  **6.2.0.0**

## Update2

I just downloaded **Intel Processor Identification Utiilty**, and i found that ***Virtualization Technology*** isn't supported by my processor.
[image: hardware virulazation]

so Haxm can't work on my pc ? should i just need to delete it ?

## Update 3

hopping that i can still use Android Emulator in VS2017.
unchecking HAXM installer in ANDROID SDK extra Tools, dosen't prevent the launch of the emulator, so do i still need to uninstall android emulator ?
[image: HAXM INSTALLER]

Comment: VT-x appears disabled *because* of HAXM.

Comment: but HAXM needs hardware virtualisation to work not? it's disabled too !
in the [intel site](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80815/intel-core-i5-4590-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz.html) , my cpu is marked as supported virtualisation

Comment: Yes. When HAXM is active, it masks VT-x for *all* other programs. I don’t get what you mean by “it’s disabled too”. Did you fully uninstall HAXM?

Comment: the first ligne " Virtualisation Technology" shouldn't be active ? to be able use HAXM ?

Comment: Like I said: While HAXM is running, VT-x is masked. So is it running or did you remove it?

Comment: no i didn't remove it , it is marked stopped